# Popup with same target location shows appears differently

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

I have two popups that come from in line code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    Sys.debug = true;
    var popup;
    Sys.require(Sys.components.popup, function () {
        popup = Sys.create.popup("#popup", {
            parentElementID: "target",
        });
    });
    var popup2;
    Sys.require(Sys.components.popup, function () {
        popup2 = Sys.create.popup("#popup2", {
            parentElementID: "target",
        });
    });
</script>
```

This is the "target" they are referencing:

```
<span id="target" style="position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%; margin-top: -125px;
    margin-left: -200px;"></span>
```

Inline Code:

```
<div id="popup" style="background: #EAFDB3; color: #000; padding: 15px; margin: 0px">
     //content
</div>
```

And:

```
<div id="popup2" style="background: #EAFDB3; color: #000; padding: 15px; margin: 0px">
     //content
</div>
```

The call:

```
<script>        
    Sys.onReady(function () { 
        popup.show(); 
    })
</script>
```

Or:

```
<script>        
    Sys.onReady(function () { 
        popup2.show(); 
    })
</script>
```

When I call the first popup it shows up in the middle of the screen as a popup. The second one (popup2) does not. It shows up at the top left of the screen pushing the rest of the content down. Why?

Edit, here is the css:

```
#popup
{
    width: 400px;
    height: 250px;
    overflow: scroll;
    background-color: #EAFDB3;
    border: solid 2px black;
}
#popup2
{
    width: 400px;
    height: 250px;
    background-color: #EAFDB3;
    border: solid 2px black;
}
```

Comment: I'm betting it's got to do with the CSS float settings of the second popup.